# Admob is not working in IOS

Tags: meteor, admob, cordova-admob

Admob is not working in IOS but it is working in the Android. Please help me out for the same.

Application is in Meteor JS. I have used following plugins of cordova but got the same issue working in Android but not in IOS.

Following are the plugins I have checked with:

```
cordova-plugin-admob-free@0.17.0
cordova-plugin-admobpro@2.31.6
cordova-plugin-admob-simple@3.3.4
```

Thank You,

Comment: Please add a description of "not working" and add error stacks, if present.

Comment: Not getting any error but Ads are not showing and sometimes I get Error message in popup which says "No Ads to show". Working just fine in Android.